how to avoid fragmentation prior exception hits in application?
For Example, there is a job executed every week for index rebuild.
But the exception happening in the period of one month. If we manually do rebuild means, the exception gone.
The job executed successfully.  But could find whether the index of the table rebuild or not.
If the fragmentation of table increases and if it reaches the threshold percentage, we will rebuild or reorganize the indexed in table.
What is the solution to avoid the fragmentation before the exception hits the application?
Or any way to improve the performance happened due to fragmentation or index?
Also need clarification on when the fragmentation will increase, whether while retrieving data from database or while doing insert or update or delete operation.
Could anyone help me with it?
